# Crontab can't execute python script with error: "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted"

Tags: python, cron

I have a very simple python script that works when I execute manually. However when I set up a crontab, it finds the script but returns the error "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted".

I tried to set up a root crontab with the command

```
sudo crontab -e
```

but the same error occurs.

Here's my crontab:

```
* */1 * * * /usr/bin/python /absolute_path/test.py > /absolute_path/cron_log_test.log  2>&1
```

Edit: Everything was working great until I updated to macOS Catalina.

Comment: What are the rights on your file? You can see it with a simple `ls -l`.

Comment: Paste `ls -l` for the Python file here. That will help us understand the file privileges.

Comment: total 8
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 john  staff  159 28 Oct 16:27 test.py

Comment: there is the same topic with solution here: http://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

System Preferences > Security & Privacy and give Full Disk Access to Terminal

Comment: I saw that and unfortunately didn't work for me.

Comment: @user2726222 did you find a solution?

Comment: Updated article for this issue on Big Sur: https://osxdaily.com/2020/04/27/fix-cron-permissions-macos-full-disk-access/

Answer (score 37):

I was able to get my crontab (which calls python) back on track by giving /usr/sbin/cron "Full Disk Access".  It's important to note that simple cron jobs were still executing, but my python based jobs were returning "Operation not permitted".

The link that andrea_grioni is on the right track, but aims at giving terminal permission to edit the crontab.  This was merely a convince in my case by removing the "allow/deny" dialog.  link: [Here is a more appropriate link.](https://blog.bejarano.io/fixing-cron-jobs-in-mojave/)

Comment: Wow i was stuck on this for hours. The link's instructions are great.

Comment: so simple. so difficult to find